# Should I be using .submit to refresh a form with angular and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, forms

I am using angular and PHP to process a form. I thought it would be acceptable to use,

```
 <script>
     $('#form').submit(function( ) {
         setTimeout(location.reload(true),3000);
     });
 </script>
```

to submit my form, but that doesn't work. What I want is to refresh the browser after the submit button is clicked.

Should I be adding that to my controller?

```
rustyApp.controller('ContactController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = 'hidden'
    $scope.resultMessage;
    $scope.formData; //formData is an object holding the name, email, subject, and message
    $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
    $scope.submitted = false; //used so that form errors are shown only after the form has been submitted
    $scope.submit = function(contactform) {
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
          if (contactform.$valid) {
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '../partials/mailer.php',
            data    : $.param($scope.formData),  //param method from jQuery
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  //set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) { //success comes from the return json object
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result='bg-success';
```

**UPDATE**

```
if($scope.result){setTimeout(window.location.reload(true),4000);}
```

Worked for me!

```
            } else {
                $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                $scope.result='bg-danger';
            }
        });
    } else {
        $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
        $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed Please fill out all the fields.';
        $scope.result='bg-danger';
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: Just use `location.reload(true)` in success callback?

Comment: Do you mean `$scope.location.reload(true);` on the last line of the if  block for the success function?

Comment: I mean just `window.location.reload(true)` if you want to reload the entire page.

Comment: Wow thanks! You pushed me to use my pea-pod a little more!